# WPF material design snackbar center text and zindex

Tags: wpf, vb.net, material-design

Hey all I am looking for a way of centering my text thats inside the snackbar and to also make the snackbar domient (as in, overlay on top of everything on the page).

This is my code behind:

```
Dim myMessageQueue = New SnackbarMessageQueue(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(8000))

items.Snackbar.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom
items.Snackbar.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
items.Snackbar.MessageQueue = myMessageQueue
items.Snackbar.MessageQueue.Enqueue("Wow, easy!")
```

And this is what the above looks like:
[image]

As you can tell the snackbar is **behind** the buttons on that page when I am needing it to be above all. And also the "Wow, easy!" text is on the left side of the snackbar when I am looking to center the text.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to you to set the z index, which is easiest in a Grid.  So, XAML where the snack bar *overlays* content may look as follows:

```
<Grid>
  <Button>Back to Main Menu</Button>
  <Snackbar />
</Grid>
```

XAML where the snackbar *pushes content up* may look as follows:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Button Grid.Row="0">Back to Main Menu</Button>
  <Snackbar Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

As for the centering, you can try this:

```
items.Snackbar.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
```

This will center the snackbar, but *not* the content.  This is all per Google's guidelines: https://material.io/guidelines/components/snackbars-toasts.html#

If you wanted to force central text, you would have to apply a custom Template.